# forecasting hourly variance with higher resolution data available

Tags: volatility, forecasting, variance, garch

Assume one has price data $P_{1}, P_{2}, \dots, P_{n}$ with one hour resolution and aims to forecast the variance for one hour ahead return. The first approach to try is ARCH or GARCH models. There are a lot of papers about that.

Next, assume that the goal is the same, i.e. forecasting the return's variance one-hour ahead, BUT with minute resolution data available.

What is the optimal way to use all the data?

Comment: And, is this the same as having $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n$ minute-resolution prices and forecasting return variance 60 steps ahead?

Comment: Dear  K3---rnc, no, I aim to forecast 1 hour ahead, not just 60 bars (1 min ahead)

Comment: One hour ahead _is_ 60 minutes ahead, relative to the observer. One of us is confused.

Comment: oh.. I see, my mistake. I am interested in forecasting the variance of the 60 bars (in min resolution) ahead return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Althoug I can only provide recommendation as to the forecasting task (see below), I want to point out one big caveat one has to account for: Intraday price volatility- or to be exact, the *absolute returns*, exhibit an intraday pattern which looks like a wave. This implies that the data is autocorrelated, which violates the assumptions of ARCH/GARCH models (see Andersen & Bollerslev 1997 https://doi.org/10.1016/S0927-5398(97)00004-2).

One solution is to model and filter out this pattern, e.g. using FFF-regression as in Behrendt & Schmidt 2018(https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jbankfin.2018.09.016). After that you can employ ARCH/GARCH forecasts.

One way to then retrieve a 1-hour (or 60-minute) forecast would be to use a rolling or expanding window of 60 one-step-ahead forecasts.

Additionally I can reccomend to look up HAR-models, these employ data on different frequencies, e.g. 1-minute, 5 -minute and 30-minute volatility as explanatory variables in an AR-model.

Comment: Dear @sgeorge , could you, please, clarify "One way to then retrieve a 1-hour (or 60-minute) forecast would be to use a rolling or expanding window of 60 one-step-ahead forecasts."

Comment: @ABK Given data ranging from $t=1$ up to $t=T$ one can generate a forecast for $T+1$. One then would use the data from $t=1$ up to $t=T+1$ to forecast the data point at $T+2$ (either based on the previously estimated parameters or by estimating them anew). This process can be repeated until $t=T+60$, which would be the one-hour forecast based on an expanding window. For the rolling window, one would remove an observation at the beginning when adding one at the end, resulting in a constant-length window of explanatory data.